# display an information in a page from another page in php

Tags: php

I'm building a chat system and I have a list of friend display on a page, so what I want actually is to display a div with a friend username at the top of the div went the friend name is clicked as that of Facebook.

**chat.php**

```
<a href="view.php?id=<?php echo $rowf['friend_uid'].'<br>'; ?>">
<?php echo $rowf['friend_uid'].'<br>'; ?></a>
```

**view.php**

```
if(isset($_GET["id"])){
   echo '<div class="chat">'.$_GET[ "id"].'</div>';    
}
```

how will I echo data in view.php in chat by clicking on the username with a link to `view.php`

Answer (score 0):

1. when you click the friend name fetch the friend_id and user_id
2. Use a query to fetch the records from message table between this two id
3. display the fetched records in the format you wanted to print

Comment: that is my problem how to display that friend_id and user_id in the page were the username is click.

Comment: make your backend API like that you can determine weather the message is send by you or you received a message then make two different div with diff class one for sender and other for receiver make css for both like **float:left** and **float: right**